# how to multiply two conditional probabilities in general

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

I am trying to understand how to multiply two conditional probabilities. $P(X|C) \times P(C| P,S)$ seems to equal to $P(X,C | P,S)$. How to understand this? I understand the product rule, but how would that apply here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the definition of conditional probability:
$$
P(X|C) P(C| P,S) = \frac{P(X,C)}{P(C)} \frac{P(C,P,S)}{P(P,S)}
$$

Only in the specific case where the events $X$, $C$ and $(P,S)$ are independent we can write:
$$
P(X|C) P(C| P,S) = \frac{P(X)P(C)}{P(C)} \frac{P(C)P(P,S)}{P(P,S)}
$$
$$
P(X|C) P(C| P,S) = \frac{P(X)P(C)P(P,S)}{P(P,S)}
$$
And, so,
$$
P(X|C) P(C| P,S) = \frac{P(X,C,P,S)}{P(P,S)}
$$
$$
P(X|C) P(C| P,S) = P(X,C|P,S)
$$
or, equivalently
$$
P(X|C) P(C| P,S) = P(X,C)
$$

I emphasize that if the events are independent, the above equality holds.

An example where the equality does not hold is the following. We deal one card from a deck, and we will consider the following events:

- Let $X$ be dealing a 10;;
- Let $C$ be dealing a clubs card;
- Let $P$ be dealing a black card (clubs or spades); and
- Let $S$ be dealing a 7.

We have that $P(X | C) = 1/13 > 0$ and also $P(C | P,S) = 1/2 > 0$. However, $P(X,C | P,S) = 0$, because when we deal **one** card it can't be the 10 of clubs and a black 7 simultaneously.